# Selenium, how to press ENTER key, no element

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, web-scraping, element

I am using the firefox selenium plugin and I cannot figure out send the enter key following a paste of some text.
This ENTER depress is 'not/no/nope' to be depressed anywhere else on the page i.e. no element switch.
Just a 'dumb' ENTER key depress?

error

```
[error] Element name=code not found
```

code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="https://www.facebook.com/" />
<title>New Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/br.rall/posts/10153787412985552?comment_id=10153787988345552&amp;reply_comment_id=10153788588305552&amp;notif_t=feed_comment</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>//div[@id='js_k']/div[5]/div/textarea</td>
    <td>In recent history, the phrase is most closely identified with critics of the economic policies known as &quot;Reaganomics&quot;. David Stockman, who as Reagan's budget director championed Reagan's tax cuts at first, but then became critical of them, told journalist William Greider that the &quot;supply-side economics&quot; is the trickle-down idea: &quot;It's kind of hard to sell 'trickle down,' so the supply-side formula was the only way to get a tax policy that was really 'trickle down.' Supply-side is 'trickle-down' theory.&quot;[4][5] Political opponents of the Reagan administration soon seized on this language in an effort to brand the administration as caring only about the wealthy.[6]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
       <td>sendKeys</td>
       <td></td>
       <td>${KEY_ENTER}</td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

How to you press the ENTER key directly after a 'text paste' without jumping elements?

Answer (score 0):

You could send the Enter key to the body tag- as every page should have one, but it shouldn't trigger any specific elements.